# Need to enter value in text field on label where value from input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I need to get value attribute from this table data `id="q5"` from input tag on click anyone of the radio button and show it label which `id=R1` is it possible???

For example if I click radio button 4 that button value 4 should be return to label text

```html
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="Q5" CssClass="lb1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td class="rating" id="Q5">
<input type="radio" id="qs55" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="qs55" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="qs54" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="qs54" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="qs53" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="qs53" title="Average - 3 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="qs52" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="qs52" title="Poor - 2 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="qs51" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="qs51" title="Very Poor - 1 star"></label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="R1" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i used script using onclick=printlabel() in td tag i will post that code below 

`function printlabel() {
var Q5 = document.getElementByID('Q5');
var a = Q5.value;
alert (a);
document.write(document.getElementById('R1').innerText);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the next label's title property and assign it to R1:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=radio").change(function() {
        $("#R1").text($(this).next("label").prop("title"))
    })
});
```

Note that you have `tr` in your question, so it's safe to assume you will have multiple questions with ratings - so the "#R1" code will only set one of them, you can get around this with:

```
$("#R1", this.closest("tr")).text($(this).next("label").prop("title"))
```

however, you're also using `<asp:label` and `Q5` so I'm guessing this should be `R5` and will change to allow postback.

Here's a working fiddle with multiple rows, but I'll leave it to you to change the ID of R1 as there should only be *one* element with a specific ID:  https://jsfiddle.net/xprrxgef/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var radioValue = $("input[name='rating']:checked").val();
                if(radioValue){
                    alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
                }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="rating"]').change(function(){
    $('[id$=R1]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow - please add a (minimal) explanation as to how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
$(function (){

  $("input[type=radio][name=rating]").change(function() {
    $("#R1").text(this.value);
  });

});
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d1fq2weg/)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `change` event to radio buttons and get the selected radio button using jquery.

```
$(function () {
  $("input[name='rating']").change(function () {
    var title = $('label[for=' + $("input[name='rating']:checked").attr("id") + ']').attr("title");
    $("#R1").text(title);
    });
});
```